# sculpting - How to get rid of the bumpy surface?

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

When I normally sculpt in blender using subd (without dyntopo) the surface looks clean after applying some strokes, but when I enable dyntopo the surface gets bumpy quickly, I guess because of the many triangles added by dyntopo during sculpting.

The smoothing brush doesn't do much when I try to smooth the surface, and it leaves me with more bumps and uneven surface.

A picture showing what I mean on the model butt, (sorry can't use imgur):

https://pasteboard.co/Ixo5DOM.png

My topology is fine, I didn't use triangles or N-gons in my base mesh, and I don't have any doubles or flipped normals.

This bothers me because I want to bake the sculpt details later, and this will affect the results.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know the smooth or flatten brush is the only way to do this. You can change your brush size or strength, or you can set your dyntopo value to a number larger than the level of detail you currently have, use the simplify brush everywhere you need to, and see if smooth and flatten work any better for you with a simpler mesh.

Comment: Good suggestions, I will try them. but how do you set the "dyntopo value"? there's only a "detail size" value to change.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry.